# Solve Poisson's equation $C=\nabla^2 v$ where $C$ is a constant and $v$ my variable

Tags: partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods, poissons-equation

I want to solve Poissons equation
$$
C=\nabla^2 v
$$
where $C$ is a constant and $v$ my variable.

I want to solve over some 2D domain $D$ with the boundary condition that $v$ is zero on the edge.

How does one solve this numerically?

Comment: It depends on the particular form of the $D$ domain.

Comment: @FelixMarin It is an irregular shape (but continuous and diff.), not a circle for instance.